# execution context declared name twice?

Tags: javascript, scope, interpreter, execution, hoisting

I am studying the execution context from Javascript. But i dont understand why the "function foo" not will be over written by the "var foo". 
I hope someone can explain this, 
thank you for your respons.

function ace() {

```
console.log(typeof foo); // function pointer
console.log(typeof bar); // undefined

var foo = 'hello',
    bar = function() {
        return 'world';
    };

function foo() {
    return 'hello';
}
 var foo = 'hello';
```

}

ace();

Comment: `foo` is overwritten

Answer (score 0):

> why the "function foo" not will be over written by the "var foo".

`foo` is overwritten at the line where `foo` is re-defined

```js
function ace() {

  console.log(typeof foo); // function pointer
  console.log(typeof bar); // undefined

  var foo = 'hello',
    bar = function() {
      return 'world';
    };

  function foo() {
    return 'hello';
  }
  var foo = 'hello';
  console.log(foo);
  try {
    foo()
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("catch:", e.message)
  }
}

ace();
```

Answer (score 0):

> But i dont understand why the "function foo" not will be over written by the "var foo".

The `var` declaration does not overwrite the function declaration. They both declare the same variable, and because of the function declaration it is initialised with a function. It is only the assignment that will overwrite the value.

If you take hoisting into account, your script will behave like

```
function ace() {
    var foo, bar;
    var foo = function() {
        return 'hello';
    }
    var foo;

    console.log(typeof foo); // function
    console.log(typeof bar); // undefined

    foo = 'hello';
    bar = function() {
        return 'world';
    };
    console.log(typeof foo); // string
    foo = 'hello';
}
ace();
```

Comment: Thank you for your respons. But are functions not created on the activation object before variables? But why is the name of "function foo" wil be overwritten by the "var foo"? Im sorry, im trying to understand it

Comment: @Overste: A function is no special type of variable. The function declaration just declares a variable and initialises it with the function object. The variable declaration just declares the same variable, and unless it existed already, initialises it with `undefined`. `function foo` is *not* overwritten by `var foo` - the `foo` is overwritten by `foo = …`.

Comment: Thank you for your respons. i Think i got it thank you. But i have last question: i read article he said: Even though foo is declared twice, we know from the creation stage that functions are created in memory  before variables. is it than not:  var foo = function() {
        return 'hello';
    } and than  var foo, bar;

Comment: @Overste The point is it doesn't matter. Actually [the spec says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) functions are initialised in the end, but really they are all the same type of binding (variable), and all created at once.